Serilog - level of details
I am using serilog to write logs to the database, its a .net core app. The issue is that I have 11 records (rows) inside the table... Its important for me to have a request and response body. I am sure that can be summed in less rows, just not sure how...
This is my settings inside the appsettings.json.
  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(Configuration)
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .WriteTo.Console()
    .CreateLogger();

and startup class
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(Configuration)
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .WriteTo.Console()
    .CreateLogger();


Here is a screenshot of a message template column
[]

What do you mean by request and response? If you mean ASP.NET Core request logging it has to be enabled explicitly using app.UseSerilogRequestLogging();. The Serilog docs I linked to show how to reduce the noisy ASP.NET Core events.

I already have a request and response inside the database, but except of that, I dont need anything else... I ll take a look at the documentations, thank you.

That isn't shown in the screenshot. All those events look like the noise generated if you lower the level of the Microsoft category. That's why it's set at Warning by default.
